# how to render dynamic menus based on logged user role on symfony2

Tags: templates, symfony, menu, twig, role

Which is the best practice to generate in a template a dynamic menu (the menu will be present in all the other app's pages) depending on the user role? 
i'm using this in my main template:

```
{{render(controller('AcmeMainBundle:Sidebar:show'))}}
```

and this is the controller

```
class SidebarController extends Controller {
    public function showAction() {

        $userRole = $this->getUser()->getRoles();        
        if (in_array("ROLE_ADMIN", $userRole)) {
            return $this->render('AcmeMainBundle:Sidebar:sidebarAdmin.html.twig');
        } else {
            return $this->render('AcmeMainBundle:Sidebar:sidebarUser.html.twig');
        }
    }
}
```

but i think it isn't good; what do you think? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this at the view level too. In the template, check the active user's role and hide/show menus depending on the role

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') and not is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}

//Show admin stuff

{% else if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}

//Show user stuff

{% endif %}
```

Comment: I thought this too but i don't like adding logic in the view level, although it's very simple, it may be an option, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the same template for both and not have logic in the template, you can pass parameters to the render method to provide the elements that will be present in your menu.